# Database engineering: Many Rows or extra backup columns for a scenario like Extendable Profile Table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I have a decision to make for a database with up to 20,000+ student profiles, Each student profile have more than 120+ Property,

In many Enterprise projects like DOTNETNUKE CMS, the used method is two tables, one is
UserProfile :

```
[ProfileID],[UserID],[PropertyDefinitionID],[PropertyValue]
```

and the other is : ProfilePropertyDefinition

```
[PropertyDefinitionID],[DataType] ,[PropertyCategory],[PropertyName]
```

If i used this method i will have 20,000 x 120 = 2.4 million row!

I know this is the correct way, to have a normalized database, and I know, the Database servers were created to handle millions of records, but i am wondering, why don't we create one profile table with 120 column + enough backup columns for the extensibility? If the performance is important, Does it more harm than good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why don't we create one profile table with 100 column + enough backup columns for the extensibility?

Your other design is more extensible.  You're not limited to 120 rows.

As far as performance, you'd have to test the two different database designs, but you're talking about a ProfilePropertyDefinition table with potentially 2.4 million 100 byte rows as opposed to 20 thousand 50 kilobyte rows.

Unless you're reading all the rows all the time, shorter rows generally perform better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, reading all the rows all the time is rare, but what about reading / managing a student profile, it'll be much more harder and slower right?

Comment: @Ala: A little harder, sure.  You have to join the tables.  As far as slower, will you read all 120 properties all the time, or will you just need a subset most of the time?  Reading a subset would generally be faster.

Comment: thanks for your reply, in most cases i'll need to get the 120 properties together on the Profile's Page-load event, The truth is, i've asked this question because i am afraid of querying 2.4 million Rows! wouldn't it be dangerous?

Comment: @Ala: No.  Databases are designed to handle billions of rows.  Where you run into problems is when the row length in bytes exceeds a database defined maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I'll go with the method of the ProfilePropertyDefinition table.