# having the same data values into more than one database table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a database with 200 thousand student records, each student have an extendable profile.

`Students` is the Primary key table,

`StudentProfiles` is stores the Profiles elements:

```
[ProfileID],[StudentID],[PropertyDefinitionID],[PropertyValue]
```

Each profile contains around 120 Property, so In `StudentProfiles` i have 200 thousand students * 120 Profile Properties = 24 Million rows.

Some important Profile elements like `Count(StudentSiblings)` or `GuardianEmail` are used in many external operations, while the other profile elements are used rarely.

For better performance, Is there any problem if we also saved this 3 or 4 Profile Properties as columns in the master `Students` Table?

This is just an Example, i also have another case where i want to save the result of an aggregate function for a table in another table for easier and faster access,  like storing the Sum of payments for a student in the students table as column, is that kind of Denormalization breaks the DB design standards.

Comment: In other words, I have a big database and my task is to make the performance better, let's say i want to save the Credit Value for students in the students table, which is the result of executing an external function,  and when any update happens in the related tables i will call the that function again and update the result in the Students table , is that kind of Denormalization breaks the DB design standards?

Comment: You have now discoverd why EAV tables are a very poor way to go about designing a database. Any columns that you know should exist should have orginally been put into the student table or a related table if a one to many relationship exists. EAV should only be inused in the VERY RARE cases when the type of data you will want to store cannot be known in advance (think things like the details of lab tests which will be different for each test and will expand each time you add another test). Your entire database design is terminally flawed and should be replaced immediately.

Comment: @HLGEM, Thanks for your comment, i will take the 'Hot' data out of the EAV table to be a real Relational in the correct place, EAV  table (StudentProfile) will hold the static profile data only. Correct me if i am wrong please.

Comment: Well frankly I would not consider using an EAV table at all.  I can think of nothing in the realm of studnets that can;t be defined in advance. You lose data interity with EAV as well as the perormance hit, it should only be used for things which cannot be defined in advance and if you must have user-defined fields (which is a poor idea usually in most business domains at least 90% of the fields can be figured out in advance and the ones that can't be often need new application developement to use them anyway)).

Comment: @HLGEM, Thanks for your comment, It was a hard decision to make, for sharing knowledge, please check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937829/database-engineering-many-rows-or-extra-backup-columns-for-a-scenario-like-exte) regarding using an EAV instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these frequently used profile elements are atomic - ie each student has only one value for GuardianEmail - then I see no reason why not to store these values in the students table, in the same way that you would store the student's email or surname in the students table.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, sorry my example wasn't clear enough actually, I have a big database and my task is to make the performance better, let's say i want to save the Credit Value for students in the students table, which is the result of executing an external function,  and when any update happens in the related tables i will call the that function again and update the result in the Students table , is that kind of Denormalization breaks the DB design standards?

Comment: @ala, you should take the data out of the EAV table when you move it to the correct place.

Comment: @Ala: Aggregate fields must not be stored in the students table (this info wasn't in the question when I originally answered). They are a very bad idea anyway and mean that you have to perform two updates whenever a base value is changed: the value itself and the aggregate. Such operations can easily cause problems (what if a second person updates a base value before the aggregate has been calculated for the first update?).

Comment: @No'amNewman, You're right, Data integrity is more important than performance anyway. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @HLGEM, Thanks for your comment, i will take the 'Hot' data out of the EAV table to be a real Relational in the correct place.